# Updating embedded object that referenced to another collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Consider this model for `posts` collection:

```
{
  id: 123,
  title: "Hello World",
  user: {
    id: 999,
    name: "John"
  },
  body: "Lorem ipsum"
}
```

Then i have `users` collection:

```
{
  id: 999,
  name: "John",
  email: "john@john.com",
  group: {
    id: 888,
    name: "admin"
  }
}
```

Lets say one day, John decided to update his name to "John Doe",
Now that means every time a user updated their name:

1. i have to update the document on `users` collection
2. i have to find all documents in `posts` collection that user is equal that updated user's id, and update the name

is this considered a good practice? 
is there another better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is actually the only way to update a field that is shared between documents in different collections.
An alternative solution is to consider changing how the data is modeled. You can [embed](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-embedding) the posts documents related to each user in his own document in users collection. Like the following:

```
{
  id: 999,
  name: "John",
  email: "john@john.com",
  group: {
    id: 888,
    name: "admin"
  }
  posts: [
    {
      id: 123,
      title: "Hello World",
      body: "Lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
      id: 235,
      title: "Hello World 2",
      body: "Lorem ipsum 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, each user has a list of posts embedded to his own document. When you update the name of the user, you wont need to update it again in other documents. However, this data model may not fit the needs of your app.
For example, you may want to have a view that shows posts from different users based on a specific criteria [publish date, popularity,...], in that case it will be harder to query the posts documents for all users that match your criteria. MongoDB provides the [Aggregation Framwork](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to make this possible.

A few general tips about update:

1. If you have a massive number of posts (like tweets in twitter or posts in facebook), consider dividing the update into several smaller(related to number of documents being updated by the query) updates [time-separated] by making use of cron jobs. Lazy update.
2. Sometimes, a referenced field may not need to be updated if it wont affect the user experience.